# HTML tables challenge

Tags: html, html-table

I would greatly appreciate help figuring this out. I'm working on a HTML table puzzle trying to match this image here:

[image]

I have everything good, make the red pillars on both sides using the rowspan tag, have the 1st, 2nd, 4th, and 5th row good, but the third row, with the three purple rectangles I just can't get to center themselves and resize to the smaller size without breaking the table.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

        <style>
            body { background-color:black;}
            table { background-color:white;
                    margin: 0px auto;
                    width:1000px;
                    height:500px;}
            td { width:200px;
                 height:100px;
            }


        </style>


</head>

<body>

    <table border="2px solid white">
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="red" rowspan="5" align="left"></td>
            <td bgcolor="white"></td>

            <td bgcolor="green" colspan="2" align="center" colspan="2"></td>

            <td bgcolor="white"></td>
            <td bgcolor="red" rowspan="5" align="right"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="blue" colspan="4"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>



            <td bgcolor="purple"></td>

            <td bgcolor="purple"></td>

            <td bgcolor="purple"></td>


        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="green" colspan="4"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="purple" colspan="4"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While there's no actual data there, I can't think of anything that would fit that structure. Why are you trying to use tables for this?

Comment: Don't use <table> for design/layout tasks.

Comment: It was just a homework exercise, not for anything practical or for graphics. Thanks dudes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need more columns:

[image]

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}
table {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 2px solid white;
}
td {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
.red    { background-color: red    }
.white  { background-color: white  }
.green  { background-color: green  }
.blue   { background-color: blue   }
.purple { background-color: purple }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="red"                rowspan="5"></td>
    <td class="white"  colspan="2"            ></td>
    <td class="green"  colspan="3"            ></td>
    <td class="white"  colspan="2"            ></td>
    <td class="red"                rowspan="5"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="blue"   colspan="7"            ></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="white"                         ></td>
    <td class="purple"                        ></td>
    <td class="white"                         ></td>
    <td class="purple"                        ></td>
    <td class="white"                         ></td>
    <td class="purple"                        ></td>
    <td class="white"                         ></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="green"  colspan="7"            ></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="purple" colspan="7"            ></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: More columns! That's it. You're help is greatly appreciated, I really appreciate the clear and helpful response. ++

You are a life saver, I understand better tables. Thank you Oriol.

Comment: @Nickolas Not at all :) Feel free to accept the answer if it solved your problem

Comment: I tried upvoting, and clicked the check mark, I believe that is what "accepting" it is. Hopefully, if not let me know and I'll gladly give you the credit.

Comment: @Nickolas Yes, exactly, [the check mark accepts the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Accepting also gives +2 reputation to you.

Answer (score 0):

Is this some kind of homework exercise? Anyways, instead of centering your table cells, try to add white table cells. You need more columns. And you have to recalculate your colspan attributes. Good luck!

Comment: Yes Armin, it's a Homework exercise, just practice, not for anything practical. ;P

Comment: I appreciate your time, as well!

Answer (score 0):

It really doesn't seem too complex.

Just draw the wanted result on squared paper and you should be able to immediately detect the correct `rowspan`/`colspan` values to use.

Just note that when writing down the HTML you need to completely skip the `<td>...</td>` for cells that end up in the "extension" of cells considered before in the sequence.

For example consider a simple 4 rows x 3 cols table:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      td { width:30px; height: 30px; text-align:center; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table border=1>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you want to merge 1 and 2 you need to declare `colspan=2` on the cell 1 and then omit cell 2. Similarily if you want to merge 5/6/8/9 you need to declare `colspan=2` `rowspan=2` on cell 5 and omit the merged ones:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      td { width:30px; height: 30px; text-align: center; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table border=1>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=2>12</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td colspan=2 rowspan=2>56<br/>89</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you 6502, but why would you skip the table data tags for cells in the extension?

Comment: @Nickolas: because that's how colspan/rowspan work... just imagine that in a table the browser starts reading from left to right each row starting from the top row until the bottom row looking for `<td>...</td>` definitions. If however a cell has been "covered" because a previous one used `colspan`/`rowspan` then that cell is simply skipped. See added example.

Comment: Oh, ty! StackOverflow is the best.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative could be **flexbox**.  I'm not saying it's better than a table, but this could be done as follows:

See: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

While I am very fond of flexbox, a table works at least as well for this issue (though if what you wanted were to change the right ways flexbox may become a better solution).

style:

```css
#parent {
  
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-left: 20vw;
  padding-right: 20vw;
  background-color: red;
  
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  
  -webkit-align-items: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
  
  height: 100vh;
}

.row, .row-sm {
  padding: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;

  flex: 1;
  background-color: white;
  
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  
  -webkit-align-items: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.row:last-child {
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

.row > div {
  flex: 1;
}

#centered {
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#centered > div {
  flex: initial;
  width: 40%;
  background-color: #655900;
}

#sm3 {
  flex: .5;
  
  /* This would not require the spacing divs; however, the start and end gap would be half the size it should be
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
  justify-content: space-around;
  */
}

#sm3 > div {
  width: 16.6666%;
  background-color: white;
}

#sm3 > div:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #111155;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.purple {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="row" id="centered">
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="blue"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="sm3">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="green"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="purple"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**NOTE:** While this version scales, it could also be adjusted to have fixed content sizes; however, fixed content sizes could be done easily without flex anyway (just divs width widths/heights padding, ect).

Comment: Hey csga thank you for letting me know about flexbox, that's sweet man. It was for an exercise on HTML Tables, tho. ;)

Comment: @Nickolas Sure!  I figured you needed a table related answer; however, I thought this may be useful to anyone whom stumbled across your question looking for related information.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        td{
            width: 75px;
            height: 100px;
        }
        .r{
            background-color: red;
        }
        .w{
            background-color: white;
        }
        .g{
            background-color: green;
        }
        .b{
            background-color: blue;
        }
        .p{
            background-color: purple;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td class="r" rowspan="9" colspan="2" style="width:150px;"></td class="r">
            <td class="w" rowspan="2" colspan="2"></td class="w">
            <td class="g" rowspan="2" colspan="3"></td class="g">
            <td class="w" rowspan="2" colspan="2"></td class="w">
            <td class="r" rowspan="9" colspan="2" style="width:150px;"></td class="r">
        </tr>
        <tr>

        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td class="b" rowspan="2" colspan="7"></td class="b">
        </tr>
        <tr>
            
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="w" style="height: 50px;"></td class="r">
            <td class="p" style="height: 50px;"></td class="r">
            <td class="w" style="height: 50px;"></td class="r">
            <td class="p" style="height: 50px;"></td class="r">
            <td class="w" style="height: 50px;"></td class="r">
            <td class="p" style="height: 50px;"></td class="r">
            <td class="w" style="height: 50px;"></td class="r">
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="g" rowspan="2" colspan="7"></td class="r">
        </tr>
        <tr>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="p" rowspan="2" colspan="7"></td class="r">
        </tr>
        
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

click[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73221625/19683045)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).